# Javascript replace string with <NewWord> comes back empty

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a javascript string like below:

```
var content = 'Robert John Testy'
content = content.replace('John','<MiddleName>');
```

It returns `'Robert Testy'` instead of `'Robert <MiddleName> Testy'`

Any idea's? Thanks.

Comment: No, it returns `'Robert <MiddleName> Testy'` - if you can't see it your likely viewing it in an HTML context where its perceived as a mangled tag and removed.  console.log() it.

Comment: It works fine. Are you substituting <MiddleName> with another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running it in `HTML` context:

In that case you must use `'&lt;MiddleName&gt;` which will be displayed as `<MiddleName>` when rendered in HTML

```
var content = 'Robert John Testy'
content = content.replace('John','&lt;MiddleName&gt;');
```

Just demonstrating the difference between both:

```html
 <html>
  <body>
     <div id="results1"> </div>
     <div id="results"> </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
             var content = 'Robert John Testy'
             content = content.replace('John','&lt;MiddleName&gt;');
             document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML =content;
             content = 'Robert John Testy'
             content = content.replace('John', '<MiddleName>');
                
             document.querySelector("#results1").innerHTML =content;

     </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```